# why are Key events c++ WxWidgets not being caught?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Good day guys

I am using WxWidgets 2.8. I have created a grid like interface using text boxes. I would like to change the values in text boxes by simply navigating to them using the arrow keys.

I have set up a panel in which the text boxes are placed, then added a onkeydown event which should just display a message when a key is pressed. This does not work.

I have tried oncharevent, and even adding the the events to the wxFrame.

Why can I not catch the key events?

Answer (score 0):

Only the currently focused window gets the key events and the frame will never have focus if it has any children taking it, such as text controls.

Also do consider using wxWidgets 3.0 for any new code, in particular it provides [Bind()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a0f30c8fa5583b4a5f661897d63de3b62) which can be convenient for handling key events from all your controls in a single place if this is what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks VZ, I will try 3.0, but for now I have resorted to using a timer and polling the keyboard. Can you tell me why the library is setup like that to only catch key events on the focused window, surely this is really inconvenient?

Comment: Using the timer to poll the keyboard is a really horrible solution, you _will_ have problems with it. Even with 2.8 you can (and should) use `Connect()` or `PushEventHandler()` instead. As for the keyboard events, this is what you'd expect in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Ok. I must admit that I am a novice at this. I have seen the connect() being used by the automated code and didn't pay much attention to how it actually works. I will read up on it. Thanks for all your advice.